# "(In) where you are"

Tags: sentence-construction, questions

I understand the meaning of "where you are", but I'm not sure if it is grammatically correct to use the phrase in the following example -

If I already know where you have moved to and wonder if you're happy living there, is it grammatically correct ask "Are you happy where you are?" Or maybe it should be "Are you happy in where you are?"

Answer (score 0):

"Are you happy where you are?" is perfectly fine, but maybe "Are you happy there?" is slightly more idiomatic.

"Are you happy *in* where you are?" is ungrammatical. "In" and "where" conflict and cannot be used together in this way [*]. But you could say, for example, "Are you happy in Texas?"

<sup>* You might see something like "Go **in where** the blue sign is." But this is different; "in" is part of the phrasal verb "go in" and "where" introduces the location.</sup>